# Kendo Treelist issue when filtering

Tags: filter, kendo-ui, telerik, treelist

We have a Telerik/Kendo treelist on an MVC project and we are facing the following issue: when filtering the list, the "Add row" functionality doesn't work anymore (either "Add row" or "Add child").

I tried to call directly `$('#mygrid').data('kendoTreeList').AddRow()` in both cases (filtered and not filtered), nothing happens when the treelist is filtered, which seems to be a bug from the framework.

Does anyone face this issue? 
Unfortunately, the treelist doesn't seem to be as popular as the treeview, thus there is not as much information about it.